# checkbox object IF statement does not recognize the variables in MATLAB GUIDE

Tags: matlab, user-interface, plot, axes

everyone. Probably, I am making a utterly silly mistake here but here is the problem:

I have made a GUI using MATLAB GUIDE. I added some checkboxes to the GUI so that they will plot something on axes2 if checked and delete it otherwise. In case if you ask, there are going to be other plots so there is hold on and off. It works like this:

```
function checkbox1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% Hint: get(hObject,'Value') returns toggle state of checkbox1
if get(hObject, 'Value') == 1
    axes(handles.axes2);
    x = handles.x;
    distanceX_Plot = evalin('base', 'CAN2_MPC_C19_Dist_X_VehObj0_Cval_MPC');
    hold on;
    distanceX_Plotted = plot(x,distanceX_Plot, 'r');
    legend('Distance X')
    hold off; 
else 
    delete(distanceX_Plotted);
end
```

but the distanceX_Plotted in the IF part gets underlined and says variable might be unused and the second distanceX_Plotted in the ELSE statement says that variable may be used before it is defined.

The complete error is like this:

Undefined function or variable 'distanceX_Plotted'.

Error in untitled>checkbox1_Callback (line 224) delete(distanceX_Plotted);

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 95) feval(varargin{:});

Error in untitled (line 42) gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in matlab.graphics.internal.figfile.FigFile/read>@(hObject,eventdata)untitled('checkbox1_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject)) Error while evaluating UIControl Callback

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current function will:

1. Create a set of axis and plot data. This plot is accessible with the handle `distanceX_Plotted`.
2. Attempt to delete `distanceX_Plotted`, which does not exist since it didn't enter the first part of the if-else block.

If you want to plot something on the axis `handle.axis2` or delete it, you need to plot in the wanted axis, or delete the axis (and not the plot):

```
function checkbox1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% Hint: get(hObject,'Value') returns toggle state of checkbox1
if get(hObject, 'Value') == 1
    x = handles.x;
    distanceX_Plot = evalin('base', 'CAN2_MPC_C19_Dist_X_VehObj0_Cval_MPC');
    hold on;
    distanceX_Plotted = plot(x,distanceX_Plot, 'r','Parent', handles.axes2); % modified
    legend('Distance X')
    hold off; 
else 
    delete(handles.axes2); % modified 
end
```

EDIT: If you would like to remove the last line you have plotted, write this in `else` block:

```
if ~isempty(handles.axes2.Children)
    delete(handles.axes2.Children(end));
end
```

It will remove the last line you printed on `axes2`.

Comment: I did not have have a chance to test it yet but it seems like that was the problem. Thank you very much for that but I have one more question: what should I do if I want to delete that particular plot not the entire axes2 in case other function plot something on axes2 too?

Comment: You can check if an element exist before you delete it with `exist('distanceX_Plotted')`, and you can get the list of children of your axis by typing `handles.axes2.Children`. This lets you decide which of these elements you want to delete if they exist (ex: the last `line` element).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There is something wrong with the if statement. I put a breakpoint at "hold off" line in my code and then checked  exist('distanceX_Plotted') which returned 1 as expected. But when I continue to run the my program exist('distanceX_Plotted') starts to return 0 as soon if goes out of that if statement. I seriously do not get this behaviour, I think I am missing something very trivial here.

Comment: Since I forgot to specify that I only want to delete that line in the axis, I will go ahed and accepts this as the answer.